# JavaScript constructor function, prototype attach method, and 'this'

Tags: javascript, prototype, this, function-constructor

I'm working through CodeAcademy JS excercises and have a question about this example:

```
//Animal class
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

//Attach sayName method to Animal class
Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
};

//create an animal object instance
var dog = new Animal('Barker');

//invoke a method attached to the prototype from the object instance
dog.sayName();
```

My understanding of this code is:

1. JS creates a new Animal object instance that var dog points to as a result of the use of the new keyword before the call to function `Animal()` - a function constructor
2. The prototype of the var dog object has the `sayName()` method attached to it in the line: `Animal.prototype.sayName = function()`
3. Because `sayName()` was attached to the class `prototype`, the method is now available to any objects created from the `Animal` class through use of the `new Animal()` function constructor

Is this a correct understanding of what is happening with this code?

Also, I'm trying to understand how `this` points to the Animal object in `this.name`:

```
Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
};
```

Doesn't `Animal.prototype` point to an actual object: the `prototype` object of this `Animal` object instance? If so, shouldn't `this` in `this.name` point to `Animal.prototype`, since `sayName()` is actually being invoked from `Animal.prototype`?

My understanding of the context for `this` is that `this` always points to the object that invokes the function. However, in this case, when `dog.sayName()` is invoked, `this` points to `Animal`, which is how `this.name` equals `'Barker'` when it is logged to the console. 
I'm guessing that either I am misunderstanding that Animal.prototype points to a prototype object, or that JS is doing something "behind the scenes" to associate `dog.sayName()` to `this` in the context of attaching a method to the `prototype`.

Multiple questions here in this little example, but getting a grasp on exactly what is happening here will really help my understanding of these fundamental concepts.

Comment: When a constructor function is invoked it assigns it's prototype to the created object's prototype so that `dog` have full access to the functions and properties of `Animal.prototype`. You may have a look at http://qr.ae/RO44Vn for a good read about the `this` of JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [points 1-3]
>
> Is this a correct understanding of what is happening with this code?

Yes, sounds like you understand it.

> Doesn't Animal.prototype point to an actual object: the `prototype` object of this `Animal` object instance?

Yes, the `prototype` object is an `Object` instance.

> If so, shouldn't `this` in `this.name` point to `Animal.prototype`, since `sayName()` is actually being invoked from `Animal.prototype`?

No, because you called it as a method of `dog`.

```
dog.sayName();
```

If you called it like this, then yes, `this` would have referenced `Animal.protoype`.

```
Animal.protoype.sayName();
```

But that wouldn't be very useful.

> My understanding of the context for `this` is that `this` always points to the object that invokes the function.

Not quite. For the most part `this` refers to the object the method was called on, not the object it is a property of. A method can actually be a property of multiple objects, so `this` dynamically points to the object it was called as a method of.

Of course, `this` can refer to other things in other contexts, such as when not called as a method, or in a bound function using `.bind`.

Comment: So sayName() is called from dog /Animal, however doesn't actually exist on dog. Instead it exists on its prototype object, and when dog invokes sayName() JS doesn't find it there but goes down the prototype chain and finds it on Animal.prototype. This is where the method actually exists. Now since dog invokes sayName() the  'this' reference points to dog so that new Animal('Barker') sets this.name='Barker'.

Comment: @lance.parish Yep, that's how the prototype chain works.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood `this`. The value of `this` is not set when you create the function, it's an additional argument. Each time you call a function, the `this` value can change.

In case of methods, the `this` value is set to the base object. For example,

```
dog.sayName(); // `this` is `dog`
({sayName: dog.sayName}).sayName(); // `this` is this new object
(0,dog.sayName)(); // `this` is undefined or the global object
```

Comment: The last example, `(foo, bar.baz)()` is an important edge case which is not immediately obvious, nice!

Answer (score 1):

`this` has two distinct characteristics in Javascript that cause a lot of confusion:

1. it's the only dynamically scoped built-in feature of the language
2. it's treated as an implicit parameter

**Lexical scope**

```
var i = 0;
const inc = () => i + 1;

const inc2 = x => {
  var i = x;
  return inc();
};

inc2(100); // 1
```

**Dynamic scope**

```
var o = {
  i: 0,
  inc: function () { return this.i + 1 }
};

var p = {
  i: 100,
  inc2: o.inc
};

p.inc2(); // 101
```

`this` is dynamically scoped, because it's set through the invocation context.

**Implicit parameter**

Instead of passing `this` explicitly as a formal parameter to methods, it's treated implicitly. Hence you need to use `call`/`apply` to set different values (namely objects) for `this`:

```
// Note that s and t are implicitly converted to objects

const split = (o, x) => o.split(x);
let s = "1,2,3", t = "4,5,6";

// objects are passed explicitly as normal arguments
split(s, ","); // ["1", "2", "3"]
split(t, ","); // ["4", "5", "6"]

// objects (or this) are provided implicitly
s.split(","); // ["1", "2", "3"]
s.split.call(t, ",") // ["4", "5", "6"]
```

Imagine `this` as the receiving object of a method, which must be passed as the first parameter.